# Changing the Mermaid stateDiagram layout to horizontal

Tags: javascript, charts, mermaid

I need to use Mermaid's stateDiagram-v2, but it renders it top to bottom, and I need it to render left to right. Any way to achieve that?

Sample diagram:

```
stateDiagram-v2 
[*] --> NEW
NEW --> PENDING
PENDING --> PROCESSING
PROCESSING --> COMPLETED
COMPLETED --> [*]
```

Answer (score 2):

I can add `direction` directive

```
stateDiagram-v2 
  direction LR
  [*] --> NEW
  NEW --> PENDING
  PENDING --> PROCESSING
  PROCESSING --> COMPLETED
  COMPLETED --> [*]
```